# Got a error during initializing array's element globally outside main function

Tags: c++

When I compiled following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long int arr[100003],flag=0;
arr[0]=-1;
int main()
{
}
```

I got this error: 'arr' does not name a type arr[0]=-1
Please help me with this.

Comment: The `arr[0] = -1;`, that's not strictly "initialization" that's an assignment. It needs to go inside a function. You can't put regular program code outside functions only declarations and definitions (with their initializers).

Comment: Try: `long int arr[100003] = {-1}` instead of `arr[0]=-1;`

Comment: OT, but `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard C++.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Do not do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 1):

In standard C++ it is not possible assigning variable outside of function but you can initialized it.

You can't write code outside of functions. The only things you can have outside of functions are declarations such as global variable declarations (usually a bad idea), function declarations and [Macros](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) .